# Ubuntu server installation failing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server on a Dell XPS 8910 (i7 6700, 32gb ddr4). When installing, it gets to the point called: `configuring pollinate user-agent on target`. Then it says `An error has occurred. Please report this error in Launchpad`. The last entries in the log can be viewed at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSZUU.jpg

Comment: How is the PC configured - UEFI? Fast Boot off? Was the disk partitioned or left unformatted? What media are you using? Meaningful answers require background information.

Comment: You might try to check if your time and date are correct in the BIOS. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1779757